# Table wise value count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a table like this, I want to draw a histogram for number of 0, 1, 2, 3 across all table, is there a way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can apply `melt` and `hist`
for example:

```
df

   A  B  C  D
0  3  1  1  1
1  3  3  2  2
2  1  0  1  1
3  3  2  3  0
4  3  1  1  3
5  3  0  3  1
6  3  1  1  0
7  1  3  3  0
8  3  1  3  3
9  3  3  1  3

df.melt()['value'].value_counts()
3    18
1    14
0     5
2     3
```

[image]